# How to import an external JAR file in Android eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I want to import external JAR file in my android project, to test this i have only created my own jar file, after that i have done following steps.

```
1)Right-click on my project
2)Build Path > Add External JAR's > Select your archive (.jar)
```

The library.jar added to the 'Referenced Libraries' in my project, but after that still i am unable to use classes of my library. So i am not getting how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Step #1: Undo the steps you did above.

Step #2: Copy the JAR into the `libs/` directory of your project.

Only the contents of `libs/` are packaged into the APK and are available at runtime.

Comment: Ya i copied JAR into libs, after that what to do?

Comment: @AnandK: Nothing. You are done. The contents of `libs/` are automatically added both to your compile-time classpath and to your runtime classpath.

Comment: @CommonsWare Done, feel free to delete the comment above. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149822/update-external-jar-in-android-project