# Update External Jar in Android Project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

All, I have an external JAR that I'm adding to my Android project. However, as my jar is consistently updating and changing. When I update my JAR, I get the dalvik VM magic number error.

I don't understand how I'm supposed to fix this?

Here's the steps I've followed.

**Adding The Jar Initially**

1. Copy JAR to `libs` folder in my project
2. Run project

My JAR is picked up, installed everyone is happy.

**Updating the Jar**

1. In Eclipse, go to the jar in `libs` and right click -> delete.
2. Copy my new jar (same name) into the `libs` folder.
3. Receive `bad class file magic` error.

**My Troubleshooting So Far**

1. In eclipse, `Project -> Clean...`
2. Select my project, clean it.
3. Run it. Same error... magic number
4. Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Remove `Android Private Libraries`

Now the private libraries aren't being re-added. (Which equates to missing imports in my Java project) Why is this a nightmare? Any suggestions?

Comment: Off the cuff, that sounds like the updated JAR is bad. Where did the JAR come from?

Comment: Pretty confident JAR is good. If I make a brand new project, jar is included just fine.

Comment: OK, now that's strange. Worst-case, create a brand-new project that contains all the stuff from the old project. Another possibility would be to make a copy of your project directory, delete the `.classpath` and `.project` files, then re-import it (using the "existing Android code" import choice in the import wizard), and see what happens.

Comment: Update to Android Studio sometime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my issue was caused by the multiple JDK's I had. Android was defaulting to use JDK 1.7 while my console jar was using JDK 1.8